# xcopy is not working when used inside a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I was trying to use `XCOPY` in my batch file, but it is not doing anything.

The echo statement used is printing infinite times and its not terminating at all.

```
@echo off

echo "Script Started"

XCOPY "C:\Users\feroz\Desktop\Datafeed\Git Data\" "C:\ProgramData" /E > NUL

pause
```

Comment: Try to remove `> nul`

Comment: If the script is continually looping, which is what you're describing, are you sure you haven't been crazy enough to have named your batch file `xcopy.bat` or `xcopy.cmd`? If so, please change the name to something which isn't the name of another available executable, or change `XCOPY` to `XCOPY.exe`. Also please remove the trailing backslash, i.e. replace `Git Data\ ` with `Git Data`.

Comment: I was crazy, i did exactly that. Named my file xcopy. Renaming file works as expected.

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment…

If the script is continually looping, which is what you're describing in your question, you have probably named your batch file `xcopy.bat` or `xcopy.cmd`? If so, please change the name to something which isn't the name of another available executable, or change `XCOPY` to `XCopy.exe`.

Even better would be to ensure that you're calling the fullpath to `XCopy.exe`, using `%__APPDIR__%XCopy.exe`:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo "Script Started"
"%__APPDIR__%XCopy.exe" "C:\Users\feroz\Desktop\Datafeed\Git Data" "C:\ProgramData" /E>Nul
```

It's more likely that you'd want however to copy everything to a directory within `C:\ProgramData` so I'd suggest something a little more like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo "Script Started"
"%__APPDIR__%XCopy.exe" "C:\Users\feroz\Desktop\Datafeed\Git Data" "C:\ProgramData\Git Data\" /E>Nul
```

*In this case, the trailing backslash on the destination will create the directory if it doesn't already exist.*